# Ветвление маршрутов истории переходов vue router или несколько экземпляров history

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, history, nuxt.js

Кто подскажет как реализовать такую штуку:

есть четыре раздела в веб приложении, в меню четыре ссылки на эти разделы и кнопка "назад". Как сделать, чтобы переходя между разделами, нажимая на кнопку назад пользователь переходил назад по истории в этом разделе? То есть для каждого раздела сохраняется своя история переходов.

Типа как приложении вконтакте

Answer (score 0):

Решил следующим образом:

1) Кнопка назад больше не перемещает по истории, а является ссылкой на уровень вверх:

```
backBtn () {
  let result = false
  if ( this.$route.matched[0] != this.$route.path ) {
    // вычисляе предыдущий каталог
    let match = this.$route.path.match(/([\w\.\-\/]+[\w\.\-]+)\/+[\w\.\-]+\/*$/)
    result = match ? match[1] : false
  }      
  return result
}
```

2) Ссылки в меню на разделы приложения меняются при изменении маршрута (адреса):

```
data() {
  return {
    ...
    pages: {
      home:  {
        title: "Главная",
        icon: "home",
        path: "/"
      },
      services:  {
        title: "Поиск",
        icon: "search",
        path: "/services"
      },
      add:  {
        title: "Добавить",
        icon: "add",
        path: "/add"
      },
      ...
    }
  }
},
watch: {
  "$route" (to, from) {
    if ( ['/services','/add','/blog','/chat'].indexOf(to.matched[0].path) != -1 ) {
      this.pages[to.matched[0].path.match(/\/(\w+)/)[1]].path = to.path
    }
    if ( ['/services','/add','/blog','/chat'].indexOf(from.matched[0].path) != -1 ) {
      this.pages[from.matched[0].path.match(/\/(\w+)/)[1]].path = from.path
    }
  }
}
```